# how set parameters by reference in nusoap?

Tags: php, nusoap, ref

how can I set a parameter by ref in nusoap. in following code I should set two parameters by ref (status and recId). note that `&` not working:

```
        $params = array(
        'username' => GATEWAY_USERNAME,
        'password' => GATEWAY_PASSWORD,
        'from' => GATEWAY_NUMBER,
        'to' => array($to),
        'text' => $message,
        'flash' => $flash,
        'udh' => '',
        'status' => &$status,
        'recId' => &$recId
    );

    $sendParams=array($params);
    $res=$this->client->call('Send',$sendParams);
```

Comment: are `status` and `recId` primitive types?

Comment: try `$res=$this->client->call('Send', &$sendParams);`

Comment: Ok, I put a bounty on this very old questions because I couldn't find an answer anywhere.What I'm trying to do is almost the same as the OP. I'm trying to pass a string by reference and put a value into it inside the funcion. And no, putting the & didn't work.

Comment: putting a `&` in primitive values do not work. You should use a class instead

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this? do you aspect that the function call is changing those values? Can you explain me a little bit more.

Comment: I need the function to: 1 - return a boolean. 2 - change the value from the $xml parameter, returning a XML based on the boolean that is being returned.

Answer (score 2):

**About passing the values by reference:**

```php
function test_reference_in(&$array) {
    $array['a'] = 2;
}

$test_array['a'] = 1;
test_reference_in($test_array);
echo $test_array; //-> it prints 2
```

**About nusoap:**

Now in `nusoap` the client class is `nusoap_client`.
In that class you have `nusoap_client::call()` to make the soap call.

This is what appen in `nusoap_client::call()` to the array `$params` which is your `$sendParams` in your example.
I'm going to omit all the rest of the method that is not related to `$params` to explain better what's going on.

```php
/**
 * Pseudocode of call to explain the operations on $params
 * @see nusoap_client::call()
 */
function call($operation,$params=array(),$namespace='http://tempuri.org',$soapAction='',$headers=false,$rpcParams=null,$style='rpc',$use='encoded'){
    /*
       some code 
       .
       .
       .

     */
    // varDump is just var_dump so print $params 
    $this->appendDebug('params=' . $this->varDump($params));
     /*
       some code 
       .
       .
       .

     */ 

    /*
     * Here $params has been read, no write operation in there 
     * about serializeRPCParameters @see class.wsdl.php again is just reading
     */
    if (is_string($params)) {
        $this->debug("serializing param string for WSDL operation $operation");
        $payload = $params;
    } elseif (is_array($params)) {
        $this->debug("serializing param array for WSDL operation $operation");
        $payload = $this->wsdl->serializeRPCParameters($operation,'input',$params,$this->bindingType);
    } else {
        $this->debug('params must be array or string');
        $this->setError('params must be array or string');
        return false;
    }

    /*
     * Here again $params has been read, no write operation in there 
     */
    if (is_string($params)) {
        $this->debug("serializing param string for operation $operation");
        $payload = $params;
    } elseif (is_array($params)) {
        $this->debug("serializing param array for operation $operation");
        foreach($params as $k => $v){
            $payload .= $this->serialize_val($v,$k,false,false,false,false,$use);
        }
    } else {
        $this->debug('params must be array or string');
        $this->setError('params must be array or string');
        return false;
    }
}
```

So as you can see here there are no advantages to pass $params by reference.

Because:

1. $params is not modified in any way in nusoap_client::call()
2. Even if you modify $params somewhere else after you have to use again nusoap_client::call()

**What if you want to pass $params by reference in any case? Can I do it?**

Well yes you can!
To achieve that you have to copy `nusoap_client.php` and call it `nusoap_client_new.php`.
In there modify the class name form `nusoap_client` to `nusoap_client_new`.

```php
// From this 
class nusoap_client extends nusoap_base  {

// To this 
class nusoap_client_new extends nusoap_base  {
```

Modify the `nusoap_client_new::call()` method adding the ref in params like this :

```php
/*
 * Please note &$params=array() instead of $params=array()
 */
function call($operation,&$params = array(),$namespace='http://tempuri.org',$soapAction='',$headers=false,$rpcParams=null,$style='rpc',$use='encoded'){
    /**
     * Of course here you have to modify your code to make some operation on $params
     * according to your needs.
     */
     /*
       original code 
       .
       .
       .

     */ 
}
```

At the end update your code to require and use `nusoap_client_new::call()` instead of `nusoap_client::call()`.

Answer (score 1):

Excusively for Gustavo.

Up from version of [PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.incompatible.php):

> Call-time pass by reference has been removed.

What does it mean is, in version `<= PHP 5.3` code like that should work:

```
function appendA($string) {
    $stringA .= 'A';
}

$string = '';
appendA(&$string);
```

but is no longer working later. For PHP 5.4+ to make a function that is editing its parameters by reference, you have to declare it this way from the very beggining. Eg:

```
function appendA(&$string) { // <- first change
    $stringA .= 'A';
}

$string = '';
appendA($string); // <- second change
```

Please note, that with PHP 5.4+, trying to call function with `appendA(&$string)` will produce an notice and not change value by reference.

According to original question, I have not found place, where `$params` are changed during `client::call()` function in nusoap, so I see no point in providing them by reference but I may be blind. Anyway method is not declared in way compatible with PHP 5.4+, so `&` near parameter during method call will not work with those PHP versions. Method modification is required in that case.